# rake aborted! ERROR: must be owner of database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am working through Michael Hartl's excellent [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-one#sec%3auser_validations) but when trying to prepare the test database with the command: 
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
I get this error message:

ERROR:  must be owner of database sample_app_test...

which I never got when using the development database, because I had created the following database role for my Rails app:

CREATE ROLE demo_app WITH CREATEDB LOGIN

(this is using Postgresql)

Does anyone understand why this is failing in the test environment? 
TIA...

Comment: I forgot to add that I'm using Rails 3.0.9, ruby 1.8.7 and Postgres 8.4.8, and that I haven't had any of the above problems.

Comment: Ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue

Answer (score 22):

Did you ensure the ownership of the test DB? try running the `\l` command on Postgres console client and check the ownerships. you can also try the following query:

`ALTER DATABASE sample_app_test OWNER TO demo_app;`

Comment: you forgot the `;` at the end of your statement ;)

Answer (score 3):

First post, writing this down for posterity. I was having the same problem but was able to fix it. You just have to make sure you were/are signed in as a superuser when you create your databases (or the one that is throwing the error).

I was logging into psql with this code:

```
sudo sudo -u postgres psql
```

And created my databases. *This is bad*. You want to log in with these superuser credentials:

```
sudo su - postgres
```

And then after you're logged in to postgres:

```
psql
```

Then create your databases. You can kill your old databases with the command

```
DROP DATABASE "database_to_drop";
```

Recreate them and you should be good to go!