# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR: must be owner of database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psql

I'm new to rails , Some errors occurred when I tried to run `bundle exec rake test:prepare` , 
Same question had been asked [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210563/rake-aborted-error-must-be-owner-of-database) ,I have included  the psql output. Anyone can help? Thank you.

I got flowing  errors :

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  must be owner of database testp00
: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "testp00"
/Users/snailwalker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `exec'
/Users/snailwalker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
/Users/snailwalker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:435:in `block in log'
/Users/snailwalker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-(required)>'
/Users/snailwalker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:370:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:test:load => db:test:purge
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

psql :

```
   snailwalker=# \l
                                     List of databases
       Name        |    Owner    | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |      Access privileges      
-------------------+-------------+----------+---------+-------+-----------------------------
 devep00           | snailwalker | UTF8     | C       | UTF-8 | 
 myapp_development | snailwalker | UTF8     | C       | UTF-8 | 
 myapp_test        | snailwalker | UTF8     | C       | UTF-8 | 
 postgres          | snailwalker | UTF8     | C       | UTF-8 | 
 snailwalker       | snailwalker | UTF8     | C       | UTF-8 | 
 template0         | snailwalker | UTF8     | C       | UTF-8 | =c/snailwalker             +
                   |             |          |         |       | snailwalker=CTc/snailwalker
 template1         | snailwalker | UTF8     | C       | UTF-8 | =c/snailwalker             +
                   |             |          |         |       | snailwalker=CTc/snailwalker
 testp00           | snailwalker | UTF8     | C       | UTF-8 | 
(8 rows)
```

databse.yml:

```
  development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: devep00
  pool: 5
  username: taouan
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: testp00
  pool: 5
  username: taouan
  password:
```

Comment: Can you post database.yml

Comment: Hi just posted , Thank you.c

Comment: haha i just figured it out , there is a user name. "taouan"

Comment: hahaha... nice...    :)

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks RAJ for reminding me to check the database.yml file ,i put a value for username somehow and i forgot it, by default it should be a nil, So i deleted username: "taouan " then run `bundle exec rake test:prepare` it worked. Alternative way is `ALTER DATABASE testp00 OWNER TO "taouan"`

Comment: put nothing after username: solve my problem, at first I don't have the line of username: and password: and caused error.