# PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: must be owner of database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

Good morning!

Faced with the problem that when you run the tests, swears that the error with the database owner, but just before given privileges to the user at the database with the tests, please tell me where to dig.

The test itself takes place, but before it pops up this error, username and database match the settings in the database.yml

I found a similar article, but I have another error, and this decision does not apply: [ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR: must be owner of database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610753/activerecordstatementinvalid-pgerror-error-must-be-owner-of-database)

**Error Code: PG :: InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: must be owner of database test**

System:

**Rails: 5.0.0**

**Ruby: 2.3.1**

**PSQL: 9.5.3**

Comment: Do you have a database `test` defined in PG?  And is the password in the database.yml correct?

Comment: And your user needs extensive rights.

Comment: Yes, correct settings, database name and password are the same in the database.yml and most PG

Comment: The rights to the base gave when creating the database and user, but the error remained.
How betrayed rights: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on DATABASE <name_db> to <name_user>;

Comment: Without the password does not allow to run tests , I do not understand where to look

Comment: Really , no one knows ?

Comment: Look at this question, which will tell you how to find who is the owner of "test", then change the owner to your db user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165254/get-db-owners-name-in-postgresql

Comment: Thank you, it's not. On github I suggested that the error in the "issue with your development environment," but I can not figure out where.

Comment: If it was an issue with your development environment, why would it show up in your test environment?  Anyway, did you follow the instructions on that question. If so what username is the owner of "test"?

Comment: No, user privileges on a test basis, before and it worked now refuses.

Comment: Please read my question.  What username owns "test"?

Comment: No, the username does not belong to "test", the user only the privileges.

Comment: The error says "ERROR: must be owner of database test".  Keep in mind that part of test preparation involves a complete resetting of the test database and the test database prepraration is clearly trying to run a process that can only be done by the owner.  It's fine for "development" and "preprod" to just have privileges, but "test" is different.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue.
My solution was just to do what Postgres says:

```
ALTER ROLE user1 WITH CREATEDB;

# ALTER DATABASE name OWNER TO new_owner;
```